# What is the most economical way to set a cronjob on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Details: I have a web app on Elastic Beanstalk (web server) and I need several cronjobs to be executed. These cronjobs must connect to AWS RDS. For this, I created an Elastic Beanstalk Worker but I must pay for the worker instance to be available all day when cronjobs only need some minutes.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is off topic for this site. You may have more luck on serverfault.com. That said, have a look at Lambda - their free tier gives you quite a lot and it's an excellent way to pay the absolute minimum for running short jobs (their maximum runtime is 5 minutes).

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks, @l0b0 ! But I need them with more than 5 minutes. I will try on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AWS Lamda with scheduled events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) for this. To connect to RDS you need to place the Lambda function inside the VPC which RDS resides with required network accessibility.

This will work for short running jobs which does not exceed 5 minutes, which is the AWS Lambda maximum execution time limit.

For long running jobs you can start and stop a EC2 with AWS Lambda scheduled events, using [AWS EC2 SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ec2-example-managing-instances.html).

Alternatively you can also use [AWS batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) scheduled with EC2 spot instances to lower the costs.